# How is FileInfo Serialized?

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, serializable, fileinfo

I want to save file metadata (mostly path/name) along with the contents of the file.

I noticed that **FileInfo** is serializable. Does anyone know data is serialized when you save a **FileInfo** object? I would assume that only metadata is saved, not the contents of the file?

Comment: You could look for yourself - check out .NET Reflector. http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: Certainly could, just thought I would save myself 1-2 hours of work if there was a guru who knew the answer from personal experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have any information on the file contents, so no the contents won't be serialized.

File Info class link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx